# Facebook user ID. Which one?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm very confused... I try to setup a a fql fan page query, and in my search, I found that my user have several `ID`... So which should I use ?

Maybe more explaination is needed ^^

- The first userId that I found is `4101606156331` (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.0)
- The second one is `1768286839` (https://graph.facebook.com/chapit.nicolas)

Which is the correct one ? And Why there are two `ID`s ? (maybe more...)

Someone can confirm me that which is the right `ID` (`260226614127613 or 320233158126958`) is the right one for the page *CodeRougeAuto* ? Because I like this page but when I try to know if I like the page with fql in Graph explorer tool (with a active token) I got this :

```
SELECT uid 
FROM page_fan 
WHERE uid=UID AND page_id=PAGEID
```

- `4101606156331` and `260226614127613` : `empty response`
- `4101606156331` and `320233158126958` : `empty response`
- `1768286839` and `260226614127613` : `Error The global ID 1768286839 is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead`
- `1768286839` and `320233158126958` : `Error The global ID 1768286839 is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead`

Thank you for your precious help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see are the so-called *global* and *app-scoped* user_ids. If you're using v1.0 of the Graph API, the user_ids will be *global*. If you use v2.0 they will be *app-scoped*, as in your first example.

It's all in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids