# facebook incorrect ids being compared

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-apps

I am having difficulty with facebook user ids in our system. After retrieving the information via the facebook api, i store the information in the database and then use the `$facebook->getUser()` method on the page load to log the user in.

Here is the insert code I am using:

```
           $user = $facebook->getUser();
           //insert sql statement using $user as `fuid`
```

My problem is that it keeps asking for the same incorrect facebook id no matter how many times I do the following:

- clean out cookies and history
- use the `$facebook->destroySession()` method

It looks like it's the id from my initial usage of the api.

Any ideas what I should be doing?

Comment: Can you post more of your code.  getUser() should not be used to log a person in.  It merely retrieves the users ID after a user has already been authenticated.

Comment: Sounds like you might have missed the changes API v2.0 has introduced – keyword __app-scoped ids__.

Comment: Here is Facebooks example on how to use their log in.  It has recently been updated for version 2.0 of their API. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're having the "old" global ids in you database, and you app now returns app-scoped user ids.

See my answer here: [Facebook user ID. Which one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655270/facebook-user-id-which-one/24657432#24657432)